# How can i stop established connection in middle of the connection in AsyncHttpClient in Android?

Tags: android

I have created a post request in which I have sent JSON data as a request parameter. I am using the AsyncHttpClient network calling the library to call the particular URL.

I have also set the three different timeout
Code snippet:

```
private void checkValideQrCodeApiCall(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        try {
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.setConnectTimeout(Constants.connectionTimeout);
            client.setResponseTimeout(Constants.connectionTimeout);
            client.setTimeout(Constants.connectionTimeout);
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
            entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

            client.post(this, AppUrls.VALIDATE_QR_CODE, entity, "application/json",new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    super.onStart();
                    Utils.showProgress(DecoderActivity.this, "Validating QR code");
                    if (qrCodeReaderView != null) {
                        qrCodeReaderView.stopCamera();
                        qrCodeReaderView.setOnQRCodeReadListener(null);
                        qrCodeReaderView.onDetachedFromWindow();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Utils.hideProgress();
                        Log.e(TAG, "RESPONSE=>" + response.toString());

                        if(response!=null) {
//                            JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                            if (response.has("Response") && !response.isNull("Response")) {
                                JSONArray responseArr = response.getJSONArray("Response");
                                if (responseArr.length() > 0) {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < responseArr.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject responseObj = responseArr.getJSONObject(i);

                                        if (responseObj.has("MessageCode") && !responseObj.isNull("MessageCode")) {
                                            myDatabase.updateQRCode(responseObj.optString("Barcode"), Integer.parseInt(responseObj.optString("MessageCode")), responseObj.optString("Message"), myDatabase);
                                            if (responseObj.optString("MessageCode").equals("1")) {
                                                WriteRecord.writeInternalLog(preferenceUtils, TAG, "Recognized Voucher: " + responseObj.optString("Barcode"), "2", "7", String.valueOf(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()), myDatabase);
                                            } else if (responseObj.optString("MessageCode").equals("2")) {
                                                WriteRecord.writeInternalLog(preferenceUtils, TAG, responseObj.optString("Message") + ": " + responseObj.optString("Barcode"), "2", "7", String.valueOf(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()), myDatabase);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    exitfrombarcodescreen();
                                } else {
                                    WriteRecord.writeInternalLog(preferenceUtils, TAG, "QR code validated offline ", "1", "7", String.valueOf(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()), myDatabase);
                                    exitfrombarcodescreen();
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            WriteRecord.writeInternalLog(preferenceUtils, TAG, "QR code validated offline ", "1", "7", String.valueOf(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()), myDatabase);
                            exitfrombarcodescreen();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        WriteRecord.writeInternalLog(preferenceUtils, TAG, e.toString(), "3", "7", String.valueOf(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()), myDatabase);
                        exitfrombarcodescreen();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                    Utils.hideProgress();
                    try {
                        WriteRecord.writeInternalLog(preferenceUtils, TAG, "QR code validated offline ", "1", "7", String.valueOf(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()), myDatabase);
                        WriteRecord.writeInternalLog(preferenceUtils, TAG, statusCode + "" + throwable.toString(), "4", "7", String.valueOf(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()), myDatabase);
                        exitfrombarcodescreen();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        WriteRecord.writeInternalLog(preferenceUtils, TAG, e.toString(), "3", "7", String.valueOf(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()), myDatabase);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            WriteRecord.writeInternalLog(preferenceUtils, TAG, e.toString(), "3", "7", String.valueOf(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()), myDatabase);
        }
    }
```

The above method is used to validate the QR code.

Issue: If the connection established and internet connection is too slow I have set the timeout as 5000 ms for all the timeout but it will wait for the response from the server.

I need to break the connection when it's complete the timeout time. for example

If I set the timeout 5000 ms the connection only established for the 5000 ms then break the connection.

Similarly, if I set the timeout 10000 ms the connection only established for the 10000 ms then break the connection.

How can I do so?

Can anybody please replay to me for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: connectionTimout=5000

Comment: if (qrCodeReaderView != null) {
                        qrCodeReaderView.stopCamera();
                        qrCodeReaderView.setOnQRCodeReadListener(null);
                        qrCodeReaderView.onDetachedFromWindow();
                    }

Comment: ignore above code.

Comment: What do you mean by breaking the connection?

Comment: It means i want to timeout the the request.